# How do i create a cookie in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I'm trying to create a cookie to hold the;

Name, 
 Email, 
 Phone Number, 
 Job(a selection in a list/text in a field) and 
 The state of two iphone-type toggle buttons then load then all into the page when the user next looks at it,

and am hoplessly stuck. I can't find a website that helps explain it to me clearly enough. Any help at all would be amazing, thanks x

Comment: So do you have a problem with [setting a cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie#Example_1.3A_Simple_usage), or do you have a problem with building the contents for that cookie?

Comment: all of it in short. i just don't understand how they work or how to code them. the sites i've tried add in so much code and not a lot of information

Comment: Well, have you checked [the link I referred to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie#Example_1.3A_Simple_usage)? I don't think any explanation can make it clearer than the first example there, and the full JS cookie API is clearly described in the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you should use this plugin : [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Usage :

Set cookie 1 : `$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');`

Set cookie 2 : `$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });`

Get cookie : `$.cookie('the_cookie');`

Delete cookie : `$.removeCookie('the_cookie');`

**EDIT**

Let's take this HTML form :

```
<form method="post" action="somefile.php" id="mygreatform">

    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
    <input type="text" name="email" name="email"/>
    <input type="text" name="phone" name="phone"/>

    <select name="job" id="job">
        <option value="job1">Job 1</option>
        <option value="job2">Job 2</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

We catch the form submit event in javascript, in order to serialized all input values in one JSON string, and store this string in a cookie :

```
$('#mygreatform').submit(function()
{
    var formValues = {
        'name' : document.getElementById('name'),
        'email' : document.getElementById('email'),
        'phone' : document.getElementById('phone'),
        'job' : document.getElementById('job')
    };

    // Create JSON string : {"name":"...","email":"...","phone":"...","job":"..."}
    // "..." are all user inputs
    var formValuesStr = JSON.stringify(formValues);

    // expires 14 days from then
    $.cookie('cookie_name', formValuesStr, { expires: 14 });
});
```

On another page, we will try to read the cookie :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var formValuesStr = $.cookie('cookie_name');

    if(formValuesStr != null)
    {
        var formValues = JSON.parse(formValuesStr);

        alert('User email : ' + formValues['email']);
    }
});
```

Comment: so i would just link the 'jquery-cookie' thing to my main page and when i need to create a cookie i go to my own javascript page and add in those lines of codes? like for creating a 'name' cookie i would put $.cookie('name', '???', {expires: 2000 }); ? what do i put for 'the_value', the user is inputting it???

Comment: ok i think i get it. but i still have a few questions - the '#mygreatform' you put - is that the div you put the form in or the id of the form? does it matter how many form values are stored? the last two blocks of code you put, can you put that in a .js file or does it have to be .php? and is the action you put in the form referring to the file you store the cookie code etc? Many Thanks

Comment: and where you put 'alert('User email : ' + formValues['email']);', is there a way to alter that to make it all load into the fields that the user put them into instead of deleting them from it and putting up a message box?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a plugin like this one: https://github.com/ScottHamper/Cookies

OR include this script

```
/**
 * jQuery Cookie plugin
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Klaus Hartl (stilbuero.de)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 */
jQuery.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

    // key and at least value given, set cookie...
    if (arguments.length > 1 && String(value) !== "[object Object]") {
        options = jQuery.extend({}, options);

        if (value === null || value === undefined) {
            options.expires = -1;
        }

        if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
            var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
            t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
        }

        value = String(value);

        return (document.cookie = [
            encodeURIComponent(key), '=',
            options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
            options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
            options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
            options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
            options.secure ? '; secure' : ''
        ].join(''));
    }

    // key and possibly options given, get cookie...
    options = value || {};
    var result, decode = options.raw ? function (s) { return s; } : decodeURIComponent;
    return (result = new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? decode(result[1]) : null;
};
```

Useage:

```
var selector = $('#name');
$.cookie("thename", selector, { path: '/' });
console.log(selector);
```

Comment: i may sound thick but none of that makes sense. i have never coded a cookie before and although i am very grateful for your answer i just don't understand how that works.

Comment: Okay, well the first code example is a jquery script. Add that code to jquery-cookie.js and include it in the head of your document so you can use it. Then, incased in a <script></script> tag, include the 3 lines within a $(function(){ << here >> }); to register a cookie and then output it to your console. Set var selector = 'test' to see it. It is quite complicated, and you need to understand the DOM quite well to grasp it. Personally, I recommend just eating actual cookies, much better, no?

Comment: ok. could i put it into a separate js file and then link that to the html file in the head?

Comment: and would the text inputted to the '#name' still be there when the user goes back to the page the next time they are on the site?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using jquery cookie https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie which makes writing and reading to cookies extremely easy.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can set a cookie using a pure javascript

```
document.cookie = "cookieName=cookieValue";
```

The cookie will be set for a current domain. you HAVE to run this code on some server. cookies will not work if you just open a html file in a browser

Comment: so for cookieName - e.g for the name cookie - would i just change 'cookieName' to '#name' so the value in 'name' is stored in the cookie?

Comment: var nameValue = // get name value from somewhere //;   and than
document.cookie = "name=" + nameValue;

Comment: i'm sorry but that has just confused me. where you put 'get name value from somewhere', that would be javascript code for retriveing information from the #name, or a getCookie thing like $.cookie('#name'); ? i really am sorry but this is confusing

Comment: that would be a javascript code for retrieving information from a text field that contains this name. You have to set the name to the "nameValue" variable

Comment: ok i think i get that. so the code would be something like; var nameValue = //some js code to get the value// document.cookie = 'nameValue = cookieValue'??